# concatenar variable en javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Buen día, estoy realizando la validación de `inputs`, los `inputs` son generados por un `foreach` de `php`, y cada uno le genero un id y nombre único (`contador_{{$i}}`), y una `function` de onkeypress="calcular_press({{$i}})"

el `input` queda así:

```
    <form name='form_listado' id='form_listado'>
        //foreach() que genera los input
        <input type="text"  name="contador_{{$i}}" id="contador_{{$i}}" 
         onkeypress="calcular_press({{$i}})"  value="1" >
      // finforeach
    </form>
```

he encontrado una `function` `javascript` así, pero solo funciona de manera estática el valor del `input` `contador_p1`, y no se como hacerlo que sea una variable para que funcione con todos los `inputs`, ya probé varias formas de concatenación y no funciona.

`fila` seria el numero que daría valor para crear el id `input`

```
function cal_prest_key (fila){
          miForm = document.querySelector('#form_listado');
          miForm.contador_p1.addEventListener('keypress', function (e){ 
          //miForm.CREAR_VARIABLE_AQUI.addEventListener('keypress', function (e){ 
            if (!soloNumeros(event)){
              e.preventDefault();
            }
          })
        }

        function soloNumeros(e){
            var key = e.charCode;
            console.log(key);
            return key >= 48 && key <= 57;
        }
```

Comment: No seria mas eficiente registrar directamente el evento de los input deseados, que estar volviendo a registrar el evento una vez que ya se esta ejecutando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `eval` para parsear el string con el id del objeto y obtener su referencia.

```
function cal_prest_key (fila){
    var contador = 'contador_p' + fila;
    var obj = eval(contador)
    obj.addEventListener('keypress', function (e){ 
            if (!soloNumeros(event)){
              e.preventDefault();
            }
          })
        }
```

Comment: `Esta funcionalidad es obsoleta. Aunque puede aún funcionar en algunos navegadores, se desalienta su uso ya que puede ser removida en cualquier momento. Evite usarla.` https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/eval

Comment: Y que se usaría en su reemplazo.